# Is it possible giving three values to an array index in C?

Tags: python, arrays, c, ctypes

I am trying to generate 3d models(.stl files) from png images in python. In python I achieved the goal to generate a 3d model. But it is pretty slow. For example an image sequence of 300-400 hundred images take about 400 seconds to generate an stl. I have tried threading and multiprocessing for it but it doesn't seems to do the job for me. So I decided to maybe do it a little faster in the language C with ctypes and CDLL.

In python I was using numpy arrays to restore coordinate data. And each index of the numpy arrays were something like these.`[1000,800,50]` each element is x, y, and the z values.

I tried to make it in the language C but I couldn't give three values to an index. It only gave the last value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void try(int rows, int columns)
{
    int row, column, z;
    int vertices[rows][columns];

    for(row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
    {
        for(column = 1; column <= columns; column++)
        {
            z = 50;
            vertices[row][column] = (row,column,z);
            printf("%d ", vertices[row][column]);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

This is the code I was using. I don't know if it is a syntax problem. But I couldn't figure out a way to find a solution.

Output should be something like above.`[1000,800,50]...`
but it only prompts 50 in the terminal.

So is it possible to hold 3 values in each index of an array in C? so I can process the image pixel values in C and return it back to Python.

Comment: To begin with, you will go out of bounds of your arrays, as you seem to have forgotten that arrays indexes are *zero* based. That means an array of `rows` elements will have valid indexes from `0` to `rows - 1`.

Comment: As for your problem, you can only have one value in an array element. Your expression `row,column,z` is using the [*comma operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator). If you want to store multiple values you either need another array, or a structure (which is what I would normally recommend, but might not work if you interact with a numpy Python script).

Comment: In C you could use an array of structures like `struct coordinates { int x; int y; int z; } vertices[rows][columns];`. I don't know if this compatible to Python.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, using an array of `struct` instances would allow you to store three (or more) bits of data at once.

Depending on the values of the data you want to store, you might be able to 'pack' the bits into a single standard C datatype (and then 'unpack it' when you need it.

Here's an example if the data values range from 0-1023 (10bits).

```
// Uses 30 of 32bit wide 'int' datatype.
vertices[row][col] = row << 20 | col < 10 | z;
```

If you know 'z' is in a small range, you could use more bits for `row` and/or `col`